# Tomcat: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find match between the canonical context path and the URI

Tags: java, tomcat, uri, war, illegalstateexception

My team ran across this error the other day while doing testing on our internal site, and I haven't found any documentation on it.  The full stack trace, with some naming information redacted, is here:

```
    Exception in logs: 
26-Oct-2015 12:19:09.894 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-12] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [Function] in context with path [/warname] threw exception 
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find match between the canonical context path [/warname] and the URI presented by the user agent [ion=v5.201+AVR+v241&] 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getContextPath(Request.java:1963) 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getContextPath(RequestFacade.java:783) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.wrapRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:934) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:364) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318) 
at package.path.to.servlet.doPost(servlet.java:97) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) 
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) 
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) 
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) 
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) 
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 

26-Oct-2015 12:19:09.897 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-12] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom Exception Processing ErrorPage[exceptionType=java.lang.RuntimeException, location=/some/location/jsp.jsp] 
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find match between the canonical context path [/warname] and the URI presented by the user agent [ion=v5.201+AVR+v241&] 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getContextPath(Request.java:1963) 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getContextPath(RequestFacade.java:783) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.wrapRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:934) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:364) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:439) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:382) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:180) 
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) 
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) 
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) 
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Specifically this is triggered by running a db query after a session time out.  The user is prompted to login again when they make the attempt but after logging in this error is thrown.  If anyone has seen this before can you give me some direction?

Comment: what do you do in `package.path.to.servlet.doPost`:97

Comment: I get the request dispatcher to forward to the jsp that displays the query results.
`request.getRequestDispatcher(
                    "/path/to/displayResults.jsp").forward(request, response);`

Comment: what is the value of `request.getRequestURI()` at that time?

Comment: No matter how I try to capture it, I'm told "It is not a known variable in this context."  I tried debugging and stepping through everything, but it seems the URI is not defined when the error occurs.

Comment: The error is commented as "should not happen" (http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/8.0.23/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java#1963). Seems that later on `getRequestUri()`returns `ion=v5.201+AVR+v241&` (param part of a URI?). Maybe remote debugging into the Tomcat code may help.

Comment: Sounds about right, I get the "should not happen" error.  I have been trying to do the remote debugging, but it hasn't revealed anything terribly helpful yet.  I know this is related to the timeout, so I'm thinking the redirect being use there is mangling the URI.  Is that possible?